# How to set JButton width through percentage?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

I'm looking for a way to set the width of a JButton to match the width of the cell it's currently located in. I have 3 cells, each with a button, but the button size varies. I used to work a little bit with html, so all I had to do is add % at the end of variable. How can I do that for JButton?

EDIT: Just in case someone else is looking for the solution. MigLayer allows usage of percents, but I found something more soothing to my needs:

```
MigLayout("", "[grow, fill]", "[]")
```

EDIT2: As requested here's the screenshot of desired effect:

[image]

[link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjtDU.png)

Comment: What is the cell? JPanel? Custom JComponent?

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of the end effect?

Comment: @AndrewThompson sure: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjtDU.png . Before using grow and fill, buttons would be aligned in one line, but each the different size. Now when I resize the whole window, tables and buttons grow accordingly.

Comment: @PerryMonschau Not sure if it's mentioned in some other layout but in MigLayout cells represent part of frame. For example if you have a 3x3 frame (basically a 3x3 grid), you would have 9 cells, each containing a component you assign.

Comment: Well like I said earlier, `GridLayout` (with appropriate layout padding) could achieve that layout (each component same width) using J2SE core layouts.  See also, [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) (for tips on making *great* screenshots).

Comment: @AndrewThompson alt+screen ... didn't know that :) thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vedrane,

[MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) allows for using percantages as a unit of measure

Comment: Thank you. MigLayout("", "[grow, fill]", "[]") does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways:

1. [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)
2. [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)
3. todays [Miglayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)

Comment: The '[tag:wing]' tag?  I changed it to Swing.  ;)

Comment: Since I'm already using mig, I googled it and got this  which is even better for my project: MigLayout("", "[grow, fill]", "[]"). Helps fill all those nasty blanks :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

This can probably be achieved by adding the buttons to a single row [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html).